# Setting Property Value of Object in Applescript Objective-C

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode5, nstableview, applescript-objc

I am working in XCode (5) on OSX 10.9.5, creating an ApplescriptOjbC project.

I have created a new applescript in the project with a class (script) named "MSDropBox" and am using it to accept the drop of files. The files dropped have their file paths read correctly. I now just want to pass this array off to the Array Controller, which is used as the source for a table. I want the table to reflect the dragged files.

I have a method in the AppDelegate class that sets the value and I am calling it from the MSDropBox class. However, it is affecting the values in the table. I believe it is calling on the method of the class, but not object. How do I affect the object?

Below is the MSDropBox class:

```
script MSDropBox
    property parent : class "NSBox"
    property window : missing value
    property thisPageList : missing value 
    on draggingEntered_(sender)
        log "entered"
        set pb to sender's draggingPasteboard()
        set theOptions to {NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:1}
        return pb's canReadObjectForClasses_options_({current application's |NSURL|}, theOptions)
    end draggingEntered_
    on performDragOperation_(sender)
        log "perform"
        -- Get the file paths
        set pb to sender's draggingPasteboard()
        set theOptions to {NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:1}
        set theURLs to pb's readObjectsForClasses_options_({current application's |NSURL|}, theOptions)
        log theURLs
        repeat with thisURL in theURLs
            set thisURLStr to (characters 1 thru -1 of ((thisURL's |path|()) as string) as string)
            set thisPageList to thisPageList & thisURLStr as list
        end repeat
        return true
     end performDragOperation_
    on concludeDragOperation_(sender)
        log "concludeDragOperation_"
        tell class "AppDelegate" of current application
            setPageList_(thisPageList)
        end tell
    end concludeDragOperation_
end script
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C it's

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate setPageList:thisPageList];
```

The AppleScriptObjC equivalent is

```
set appDelegate to current application's NSApplication's sharedApplication()'s delegate()
appDelegate's setPageList_(thisPageList)
```

I'm not sure whether AppleScriptObjC recognizes the application delegate method without type casting, maybe you have to add `as AppDelegate`